# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < CDN

Tags: javascript

I've used CDNs for all my scripts but I get the error 
     "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <"

I've been stuck on this for hours, and I don't know why there's an error.

```
    <!-- File: chapter10/simple-routing.html -->
<html>
 <head>
   <title>AngularJS Routing</title>

   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js">  </script>
   <script src="https//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular.js"> </script>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular-route.js"> </script>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.8/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.8/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.8/angular-sanitize.js"></script>


 </head>
 <body  >
    <h2>AngularJS Routing Application</h2>

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Figure out which on of the urls above is returning HTML instead of JavaScript. comment them out one by one until it stops.

Comment: It's probably the second one (bootstrap)...because everytime I include it I get the error. but why would it return html?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

typo:

```
https//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js
    ^^
```

Comment: these typos will kill you, if nobody else, be careful next time ;)